# Pseudo elements don't appear to work in Salesforce lightning CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, salesforce-lightning

I have a list group that holds a bunch of attributes, but when I clarify that the last element within that group hold a margin of 0, the output doesn't match.

The Salesforce HTML:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.IdeasList}" var="idea">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="{!v.ideaDetailPath + idea.Id }" class="anchorLink"> 
                    <div class="prodname">{!idea.Title}</div>
                </a>
                <div class="ideaInfo"> 
                    <span class="points">{!idea.VoteTotal} points </span>
                    <span style="padding-right:24px;">
                    <span class="status">
                        {!idea.Status}
                    </span> 
                    </span>
                    <span class="createdDate"><ui:outputDate value="{!idea.CreatedDate}"/></span>
                    <!--span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_circle slds-avatar_small">
                        <img src='{!idea.CreatorSmallPhotoUrl}'/>{!idea.CreatorName}</span>
                    <span class="slds-text-title_bold">
                        <a class="profileName" href="javascript:void(0)" 
                           id="profile-link"
                           data-createdByValue="{!idea.CreatedById}" 
                           onclick="{!c.openProfileWindow}">
                          {!idea.CreatorName}</a></span-->
                   <a class="slds-text-title_bold profileName" id="profile-link" data-createdByValue="{!idea.CreatedById}" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.openProfileWindow}">
                       <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_circle slds-avatar_small slds-m-right_x-small">
                           <img src="{!idea.CreatorSmallPhotoUrl}"/>
                       </span>{!idea.CreatorName}
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-border_bottom">
                </div>
            </li>
        </aura:iteration>
```

The Salesforce CSS:

```css
.THIS .list-group-item {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:24px;
}

.THIS .list-group-item:last-child{
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Does that mean pseudo elements (specifically last-child in this case) don't work in Salesforce Lightning CSS?

Comment: Please share the HTML that this CSS is supposed to apply to.

Comment: Does it work if you add !important after margin-bottom: 0? i.e. margin-bottom:0!important;

Comment: @JesseJamesBurton it doesn't work. I've tried that.

Comment: Already done @TylerH

Comment: @Majo0od I don't see any classes named THIS in that code. Please include the generated HTML markup that the browser sees, not pre-compiled code. We need to see a [mcve].

Comment: The output doesn't matter because I'm not working on the output, I'm working within the context of Salesforce (ie: using salesforce's syntax). I think that's primarily the problem as to why the :last-child isn't outputting (maybe because I'm missing something?)

Comment: What about if you add the margin-bottom: 0 within the developer tools after the page is rendered, does it apply then?

Comment: @JesseJamesBurton you know what's odd? I changed that code to :nth-child(2n){..} and it worked... But last-child isn't working. It's making me wonder if there is another instance of .list-group-item elsewhere on the page....

Comment: And just checked: there is no other instance of that class name.... huh...

Comment: @Majo0od Well the output does matter because what you're using is CSS, which applies to HTML. At any rate, your CSS selectors still don't match any elements in your other code block.

Comment: @TylerH But the CSS is within the salesforce context, therefore the .THIS attribute is understood in salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only thing that works is `:nth-last-child(2)` - because for some reason, `:last-child` doesn't acknowledge that the last item is actually the last item.

I did a search within the HTML to check that there was no other element after the element I was hoping to edit via CSS, but there wasn't. Seems as though this is a salesforce bug? Anyway,s `:nth-last-child(2)` worked instead of `:last-child`